# Wpf Extended Toolkit: custom datetimepicker time format

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

How do I milliseconds to my string format. Here's what I have:

```
<wpfTool:DateTimePicker
                        x:Name="DTP_To_TAtab" 
                        Format="Custom" 
                        FormatString="M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
                        TimeFormat="Custom"
                        TimeFormatString="HH:mm:ss"
```

I want the time to look like this:

14:15:16.123

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#fffSpecifier) should do it

```
HH:mm:ss.fff
```

Comment: it allows you to enter numbers but when you click somewhere else or click enter the numbers are reverted back to 000 @Dtex

Comment: Seems like DateTimePicker internally is using a custom converter that will ignore the milliseconds part of the text. I don't know if you can provide your own custom converter without rewriting the source code.